# Button not printing anything

Tags: python, button, pygame

I created a function for my button. I am trying to get it to run through once per click so I integrated the lines 'for event in pygame.event.get() and pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN so it will register one click, run through once and then stop until next click. But now it doesn't work at all.
1. how do i get it to run
2. how do i make sure it runs through once per click and then resets to run through until next click. Please show example

Here is the code:

```
def Button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()    
        if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, ac, (x, y, w, h)) 
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    pygame.draw.rect(window, lightgrey, (x, y, w, h))
                    if action == "undo":
                        print("hey") 
                    if action == "reset":
                        for row in range(6):
                            for column in range(7):
                                board[row][column] = 0          
                    elif action == "quit":
                        pygame.quit()
                        quit()
```

Comment: What isn't working? Are there errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to check the event queue inside the Button function, but rather somewhere in your main game loop and then call the Button function if a click has occured. It also looks to me like the Button function you have there might be more sensibly implemented as a Button class with different methods, such as `onClick`.

Here's a small example of a code with a button class and two buttons:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# Screen size
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 350
SCREEN_WIDTH = 500

# Colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREY = (150, 150, 150)
RED = (255,0,0)


# our Button class
class Button(object):
    def __init__(self, msg, x, y, w, h, col, action=None):
        self.msg = msg
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.color = col
        self.action = action  # function that will be called on click

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, self.rect)

    def onClick(self, event):
        # check whether the click was on the button
        if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
            print("Button", self.msg, "clicked!")
            # if an action has been set, do that action
            if self.action:
                self.action()


# initialisation
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# list to keep track of our buttons
buttons = []


# define an undo function (will be passed to a button)
def undo():
    print("I'm an undo function!")

# fill screen with background
screen.fill(WHITE)

# button with no function
btn1 = Button("btn1", 50, 50, 50, 50, GREY)
btn1.draw(screen)
buttons.append(btn1)

# button with an undo function
btn2 = Button("btn2", 150, 50, 50, 50, RED, undo)
btn2.draw(screen)
buttons.append(btn2)

pygame.display.update()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  # mouse was clicked
            # check for every button whether the mouse click was on the button
            for button in buttons:
                button.onClick(event)

    # do whatever else needs doing

    pygame.display.flip()  #update display (currently not strictly necessary)

    clock.tick(60)  # ensures a maximum of 60 frames per second

pygame.quit()
```

A Button object has a rectangle. We use this to draw the button (filled with the specified button color) and to check when a mouseclick has occured whether that click was on the button rectangle, meaning the button was clicked. The message is currently only used to output a name for the button when it was clicked, but you could use it to render text on the button or whatever else you need.

A Button can also have a function associated with it. This function gets called when the button is clicked. One of the nice things about Python is that you can pass functions as arguments, so you don't have to specify in the Button class what actions might be taken if a a button is clicked. Instead, you define that function when you need to make a new Button. This makes your code very versatile. You could replace that part with a simple string and then instead of calling `self.action()` in `onClick` you do your `if else` cases as in your posted code snippet.

Then in our main class we initialize pygame and then make two buttons (one grey with no function and one red with an undo function). In order to easier keep track of them, we throw them in a list which we can iterate over later.

Now in our main game loop, we check the event queue for any events, and if some occured, we handle them. If the mouse was clicked, we go over all the buttons in our list and call `onClick`. Every button then checks in their `onClick` method whether the mouseclick was inside the button rectangle, and if yes, does the specified function (as well as outputting a debug print statement). You can modify the `onClick` function to whatever you need to do when a button has been clicked, for example changing the color of the button.

If you have other events you need to keep track of in your game, handle them in the same way with the main event queue as we've done. Afterwards, do whatever else you need to be doing, like moving Sprites or redrawing parts of the screen that have changed.

Comment: you just saved my most important final school assignment, thankyou.